# Regarding voltage regulator input and output

Tags: voltage-regulator

A}} what will be the output voltage if I'm giving 24v input and 12v in gnd in 7805 fixed
voltage regulator?

B]] if I connect the output terminal of the 7805 fixed voltage regulator to gnd and gnd to
the input terminal of the circuit, doesn't it will give me -5 volts in the circuit? so
why do we need 7905 fixed voltage regulators?

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add a schematic (using the built-in tool) which shows what you're trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

> *what will be the output voltage if I'm giving 24v input and 12v in gnd
> in 7805 fixed voltage regulator?*

The output will be 17 volts with respect to ground.

> *if I connect the output terminal of the 7805 fixed voltage regulator
> to gnd and gnd to the input terminal of the circuit, doesn't it will
> give me -5 volts in the circuit?*

No, it doesn't, the output will be shorted to ground and the GND pin cannot be used as an output or connected to the input supply voltage. The GND pin has to be at the lowest potential in the circuit or it might fry.

> *so why do we need 7905 fixed voltage regulators?*

Because you can't use a positive voltage regulator from the 78xx family in the way you described earlier.

Comment: means o/p will be 17 volts and gnd will be 0 ?? and I didn't get it how is it giving 17 volts?

Comment: GND as a node is normally regarded or stated as being 0 volts. The GND pin of the 7805 is connected to 12 volts (as per your question). These are assumptions based on you NOT providing a schematic.

Comment: yes, ik that is my assumption but what I want to know is how are we getting 17 volts in output I just want to know the process or the reason why we did 5+12.                                          btw thanks for answering

Comment: The 7805 produces 5 volts on its output pin with respect to its GND pin so, if the GND pin is lifted to 12 volts, then the output voltage (with respect to true GND or 0 volts) is 17 volts.

Comment: but if we want to measure voltage what we normally do in 2 terminals V1-V2= Vout, So the Ans should be -7 volt why are we adding 12 and 5??

Comment: I can only state what I know (fundamentally and absolutely) to be the case.